# Check availability of selected room in date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the db named *reservations* with columns: *id*, *date_from*, *date_to*, *obj_id*.

In my app, I need to create a sql query where I can check the availability of room (*obj_id*) in the specified date range.

I was trying to use something like the following but it is not working well:

```
select * from `reservations`  
where ((`date_from` <= $from and `date_to` >= $from)
or (`date_from` <= $to and `date_to` >= $to)) and `obj_id` = $obj
```

for example when some room is reserved from 2013-07-03 to 2013-07-06, date from 2013-07-01 to 2013-07-07 is treated as a free

Comment: "not working well" isn't a proper issue explanation.

Comment: for example when some room is reserved from 2013-07-03 to 2013-07-06, date from 2013-07-01 to 2013-07-07 is treated as a free

Comment: put it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Between**    clause of sql in order to filter results between two given dates. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) for details. 
Here's what you can try as your query!

```
Select * from `Reservations` where $ToDate between date_from and date_to 
            OR date_to between  $FromDate  and  $ToDate  
            OR  $FromDate between date_from and date_to 
            OR date_from between $FromDate  and $ToDate
            AND `obj_id` = $obj;
```